# Do paypal allow use of the standard api (not adaptive payments) for crowdfunding?

Tags: paypal

Not interested in pre-approved payments, there is no real way to guarantee payment to owner of a successful project, and besides, the application approval process for paypal adaptive payments is beyond timescales.

Do paypal allow use of the standard api (not adaptive payments) for crowdfunding?

Comment: Do you want to pay to the merchant or other paypal user's than merchant?
If you want to get money from people to your merchant account then go for express checkout. Else the solution is Adaptive payment.

Get more infor about adaptive payment from here:
http://youtu.be/GjEPcf7fvkM

Comment: Its not to be a really successful crowdfunding site. I guess its maybe risky scenario where the projects are all within paypals refund time limit and then putting all those refunds through if when project isnt successful

Comment: Or do you think paypal would be ok with that for a small site?

Comment: This seems like a good question for PayPal Merchant technical support https://www.paypal.com/webapps/mpp/merchant . Open a ticket with them and they would be able to verify.

Comment: well, i guess that makes sense.